# Grails, Spring Security override user

Tags: grails, spring-security

in our grails app we are using the Spring Security & Spring Security UI,

We created the User Role UserRole domain classes using S2ui-override:

```
grails s2ui-override user package.name
grails s2ui-override role package.name
```

Those work great but I would like associate three other domain classes with the User by adding the following to the User class:

```
static belongsTo = [organization : Organization]
static hasMany = [reports: Report, invoices: Invoice]
```

But when I run the app I get an error in the creation of the UserRole class:

```
Error |
2013-12-06 12:49:19,797 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   36 | create                           in stepdev.UserRole
```

What am I missing?  Did I need a different override or do I need to do something else, I would also like to add more information to the User class such as email which I tried with the same result

Comment: Could you set a verbose log level and also provide the surrounding code for the UserRole class to line 36? The s2ui-override commands are only going to affect the UI so that's not really pertinent.

Comment: In bootstap.groovy, we are creating the roles and a user but was not passing the required arguments, I either needed to make email and organization to allow null values, and/or pass the proper arguments  in bootstrap.